# The space between objects are more than given amount

Tags: java, android, android-xml

I am trying to setup my XML layout but for some reason there are a lot of space in between.

It looks like:

[image]

My XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/bginset4" >
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp" >
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTheFileName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#0093DD"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:background="#ff0000" />
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSavedTotalToll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#0093DD"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:background="#00ff00" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etFileContents"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
        android:lines="18"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textColor="#999999"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textStyle="normal" >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClose"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:text="Close Window"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="2"
        android:background="@drawable/closebutton" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I added the background color to differentiate. I am not sure why the object with red and green background has so much space below them. Any idea how to fix the issue?

I am just looking to put Trip Name and then a small space and then Total Toll Amount and then the button all the way on the bottom and any space left in between to store the multiline edittext.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `android:layout_marginTop="8dp"` from both your `TextView's`: `txtTheFileName` and `tvSavedTotalToll`. That is the reason for more space.

Comment: That just removes the white space. I meant the textview height is wrap_content but why is the green and red color stretching down so much?

Comment: Nevermind... Stupid me was using "\n" to retrieve data from a file! Fixed now. Thanks.